# Stop user being asked to log in twice for facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the facebook api with my android app to log a user into facebook, get some details and post a status. Then sometimes I also need to open a facebook link in the users web browser.

It works ok but after i have logged the user in on my app, when i open the facebook page it asks the user to log in again. Is there any way i can stop it from asking for username and password again and just have it login with the session i already have for my app?

Answer (score 0):

See what Cookie ID the Browser login generates to store the access token, and store the access token that you obtained yourself with the same Cookie ID, that way the Browser will recognize it and you will be logged in.